# Unable to resolve reference BR at runtime databinding android

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-mvvm

I am trying to use databinding with MVVM in my android app but it is giving me an error: "Unable to resolve reference BR" at runtime while i can see the class already exist in the project.

**build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    def arch_version = "2.1.0"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
}
```

**ViewModel** class:

```
class SearchViewModel : BaseObservable() {

    private  var searchModel = SearchModel("")

    fun setSearchText(text: String){
        searchModel.text = text
//        notifyPropertyChanged(B)
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR._all)
    }

    @Bindable
    fun getSearchText(): String{
        return searchModel.text
    }

    fun onSearchClicked(){
        if(searchModel.text.isNullOrEmpty())
           setSearchText("Error!!!")
    }

}
```

**Activity** class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val bind : ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        bind.viewModel = SearchViewModel()
        bind.executePendingBindings()
    }


}
```

**xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.abc.xxx.viewmodels.SearchViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inImageSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/search_hint"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@={viewModel.userText}" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{()-> viewModel.onSearchClicked()}"
            android:text="@string/search"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

So what are the changes i should do to make it work? I have tried many SO threads already but none of them is working. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are binding to a property that doesn't exit. You have the userText in your xml which doesn't exist. Also you are binding to a model of the viewModel, so you need to make sure your SearchModel also implements BaseObservable.

Then make sure it is not private in your viewModel or that you write appropriate getters to retrieve it. The get and set Names MUST match the property name that is labeled with bindable.

Also just an architecture comment. I'm not sure why you would create a searchViewModel and a searchModel. Seems sort of redundant, but maybe you have reasons.

Example SEARCH MODEL below

```
class SearchModel : BaseObservable() {

   @Bindable
   private var searchText = ""

   fun setSearchText(text: String){
       searchModel.text = text
       notifyPropertyChanged(BR.searchText)
   }

   fun getSearchText(): String{
       return searchModel.text
   }

}
```

Then your XML needs to be bound correctly to the models property

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inImageSearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@={viewModel.searchModel.searchText}" />
```